# How to extract surface vertices coordinate in fimplicit3 function?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to extract the coordinate of surface vertices in the fimplicit3 function in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't found how to do with fimplicit3, but it easier to extract vertices and faces from a surface using `isosurface` function.
One can follow this tutorial: [Implicit curves and surfaces sith Isosurface](https://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2015/03/03/implicit-curves/)